# Why is the button permanently displaying on the page?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

The below react code displays a message to the user and is manually terminated by clicking the button or is programmatically terminated after a minute. It is only displayed if the 'message' variable has a value. When it is terminated, the message variable is set to an empty string. The problem is even when the code is terminated, the message is set to null, the button within the div is displayed permanently on the page.

```js
return (
  message && (
    <div
      aria-live="polite"
      aria-atomic="true"
      className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center alert-main my-4"
    >
      <div
        className={`alert  alert-div ${
          errorMessage ? 'alert-danger' : infoMessage ? 'alert-info' : ''
        }`}
        role="alert"
      >
        <>
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <strong className="mr-auto">{message}</strong>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="ml-2 close"
              onClick={() => clearMessage()}
              aria-label="Close"
            >
              <span aria-hidden="true" style={{ fontSize: 'large' }}>
                &times;
              </span>
            </button>
          </div>
          {/* <div className="">{message}</div> */}
        </>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
);
```

function to clear message:

```js
const clearMessage = () => {
  errorMessage = '';
  infoMessage = '';
  message = '';
  ClearMessage();
  messageSubscriber.unsubscribe();
};
```

`ClearMessage()` in redux reducer:

```js
case ReducerType.CLEAR_MESSAGE:
  return {
    ...state,
    error: "",
    info: '',
    title: "",
    alertMessage: ''
  }
```

Comment: Might that be an unintended object literal (the first term of the &&) operator?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: { message } is the same as {message: message} isn't it?  I think you think this is printing out message but I don't think it is because I seem to remember react does not let you use template braces outside jsx elements.  Might be wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. I will pursue that angle.

Comment: `{message != null ? <><div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center alert-main my-4"
  > ... </>:<>//display whatever if message == null</>}`

Comment: that was the problem, user1849962. Thank you.